# clean up the data frame based on conditions

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looking like this.

Dummy Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("24/06/2002", "24/06/2002", "25/06/2002", 
                               "02/07/2002","24/07/2002", "08/07/2002",
                               "08/07/2002", "15/07/2002", "17/07/2002", 
                               "22/07/2002", "22/07/2002", "28/07/2002", "29/07/2002"), 
                      payment = c(200,   1000, 1000, 
                                  -1000,-1000, 1200,
                                  -1200, 1200, 1200,
                                  200, 56700, -56700, -200), 
                      Code = c("ABC", "M567", "M567", "M567", 
                               "M567","M567", "M567", 
                                "M567", "M567", "M300", 
                               "M678", "M678", "ABC"), 
                      ID = c(NA, "98","98","M11",
                             NA,"K999", 
                             "K999", "111", "111", "11",
                             "12345", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Some of the rows are just return of payment:

```
         Date payment Code    ID
1  24/06/2002     200  ABC  <NA>
2  24/06/2002    1000 M567    98
3  25/06/2002    1000 M567    98
4  02/07/2002   -1000 M567   M11
5  24/07/2002   -1000 M567  <NA>
6  08/07/2002    1200 M567  K999
7  08/07/2002   -1200 M567  K999
8  15/07/2002    1200 M567   111
9  17/07/2002    1200 M567   111
10 22/07/2002     200 M300    11
11 22/07/2002   56700 M678 12345
12 28/07/2002  -56700 M678  <NA>
13 29/07/2002    -200  ABC  <NA>
```

I want to delete the rows that has a same +ve and -ve payment by taking Code and ID into consideration.
i.e.,

- if the code and ID column matches and the payment is cancelling out then delete those two columns
- if ID is present for +ve payment and absent for -ve payment viseversa then only take Code for grouping
- If ID is absent for both +ve and -ve then only take Code column for grouping

So, the resultant dataframe should be like this:

```
  Date       payment Code  ID   
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 22/07/2002     200 M300  11   
2 15/07/2002    1200 M567  111  
3 17/07/2002    1200 M567  111  
4 25/06/2002    1000 M567  98   
5 02/07/2002   -1000 M567  M11
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'Code' column, then create a sequence column for each unique element of 'payment', then add the sequence also with 'Code' to `fill` the missing element in 'ID' by the previous non-NA id', `ungroup`, remove the rows where 'ID' is still NA (`drop_na`), create a column of payment with `abs`olute values, order by 'Code', 'ID' and absolute payment column, then, grouped by the same columns, create a grouping column by taking the sequence of `sign` values of 'payment', add as grouping column, and `filter` only groups having a single row

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>%
  filter(sum(payment) != 0) %>%
  arrange(Code, abs(payment), !is.na(ID)) %>%
  mutate(ind = rowid(payment)) %>%
  group_by(ind, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  fill(ID, .direction = 'downup') %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  drop_na(ID) %>% 
  mutate(absPayment = abs(payment)) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Code, absPayment) %>%
  group_by(Code, ID, absPayment) %>%
  mutate(grp = rowid(sign(payment))) %>% 
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  ungroup %>%   
  select(names(df1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Date       payment Code  ID   
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 22/07/2002     200 M300  11   
2 15/07/2002    1200 M567  111  
3 17/07/2002    1200 M567  111  
4 25/06/2002    1000 M567  98   
5 02/07/2002   -1000 M567  M11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("24/06/2002", "24/06/2002", "25/06/2002", 
"02/07/2002", "24/07/2002", "08/07/2002", "08/07/2002", "15/07/2002", 
"17/07/2002", "22/07/2002", "22/07/2002", "28/07/2002", "29/07/2002"
), payment = c(200, 1000, 1000, -1000, -1000, 1200, -1200, 1200, 
1200, 200, 56700, -56700, -200), Code = c("ABC", "M567", "M567", 
"M567", "M567", "M567", "M567", "M567", "M567", "M300", "M678", 
"M678", "ABC"), ID = c(NA, "98", "98", "M11", NA, "K999", "K999", 
"111", "111", "11", "12345", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -13L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Can you please add comments if possible

Comment: Sorry to ask again. I just realized that there are some rows where ID is missing for the negative row.  Can you please tell me how can I implement an "or statement" at group by?

Comment: Thank you very much. @akrun I just added an extra line of data . So even if ID is NA it has to check Code column and cancel out the +ve and -ve signs. ( Also updated the data)

Comment: So that three cases are covered - If code and Id both are present /  ID is present for +ve and absent for negative / ID is absent for +ve and -ve

Comment: I have updated with all the possible cases in the question with same datatypes with original data. Code and ID is not always same for all the payment rows. So, filling NAs with the use of direction gives an ambiguous answer. Sorry for re-editing I feel this a bit complicated - since I am very new to R programming

Comment: Please once run the code you provided with the updated data - u would understand my question @akrun. I ran it just now and since direction is "downup" NA will be replaced by its nearest value based on ID rather than the opposite sign's ID

Comment: I have altered the row- 4 and 5. due to which NA's replacement wouldn't be replaces as expected

Comment: I am really sorry about it. I really appreciate your time and patience. This is the last update. I am sorry again - I could not figure out a way to fill NA's with the opposite sign Code and Payment. If date is used in arrange - NAs will not be filled by checking the sign of payment

Comment: I have been manually typing the expected inputs and outputs. I have just pasted the data from the console

Comment: So, the row   --> `24/07/2002   -1000 M567 <NA>` is the return/refund of the payment --> which should be cancelled out with the original payment i.e  `24/06/2002    1000 M567    98`  or  `25/06/2002    1000 M567    98` - hence leave the remaining two rows uncancelled

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help. I have been struck at this since 4 days @akrun

Comment: Can you please tell me how  ``fill(ID, .direction = 'downup') %>% `` is filling NA with the opposite sign? because in the group by or in the mutate statements you did not mention anything related to sign of the payment

Comment: But this is working for a small dataset. If the row ``25/06/2002    1000 M567  98 `` is far away(6-7 rows above) from its Negative payment the NA is not getting filled

Comment: The only problem is to identify the opposite sign of payment and fill NA with its ID of the opposite sign. Which is difficult to write in a code. @akrun

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74086430/delete-wrongly-added-rows-with-help-of-few-columns-in-r/74086577?noredirect=1#comment130808332_74086577 - please check my newly posted question

Comment: Can we write the code in a way where - NA is filled if sum(payment) is zero and "Code" is same for both rows? - This would solve the issue I think

Comment: @bella_pa adding that additional condition, gives the same output for this example you showed

Comment: Thanks a lot for you time @akrun. But Even this way``. direction= "downup"`` wouldn't work if the rows are far way. It sure does work for the dummy data

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

- first fill missing IDs by Code / amount
- group all payments (+/-) which have the same amount, ID, Code : this gives a `data.table` subset for each group [noted `.SD`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-sd-usage.html)
- take the sum of signs of +/- payments in each `.SD`

  - if the sum is positive (for example +/-/+/+=2), filter only the positive values in `.SD` and keep the last `sum(sign)` positive values (here 2) using `tail`
  - if the sum is negative (for example +/-/-=-1), filter only the negative values in `.SD` and keep the last `sum(sign)` negative values (here 1) using `tail`
- if the sum is 0, keep 0 rows : the rows disappear as expected.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

df1[,ID:=nafill(ID,type = 'locf'),by=.(Code,abs(payment))][
    ,tail(.SD[sign(sum(sign(payment)))==sign(payment)],abs(sum(sign(payment))))
    ,by=.(ID, Code,abs(payment))]

#>       ID   Code   abs       Date
#>    <int> <char> <num>     <char>
#> 1:    98   M567  1000 01/07/2002
#> 2:   111   M567  1200 15/07/2002
#> 3:   111   M567  1200 17/07/2002
#> 4:    11   M300   200 22/07/2002
```

Comment: Thank you @Waldi. Can you please ad comments to the code. It is difficult to understand what you did

Comment: @bella_pa, see my edit with more explainations

Comment: Thank you again. How would Code- 12345 cancel out with NA ?

Comment: The `NA`s are filled in the first step described above

Comment: Is it possible to fill NA's  only taking into consideration of the opposite sign ? Instead of using abs(payment).

Comment: abs(payment) is meant to fill the opposite sign : `-1000/Code;1000/NA` and `1000/Code; -1000/NA` should work. If this isn't what you expect, please share an example.

Comment: na.fill is also not working for string type. Can you please help me out with this

Comment: For string ID, you can use `zoo::na.locf(ID)` instead of `nafill(ID,type = 'locf')`

Comment: Can you please update your answer w.r.t to updated data

Comment: I'll do this, but could you first update your dummy data `df1 <- structure(...)` which doesn't seem to correspond to the subsequent modifications you made to your question, for instance  `56700, -56900` seems  wrong.

Comment: Please check the updated data. Sorry for all the re-editing I feel this code a bit complicated ( I am very new to R programming)